# Diferenças e uso do RMI, Socket e JPA

Tags: java, java-ee

Sou novo em java e gostaria de uma ajuda para entender melhor **RMI**, **Socket** e o **JPA**, e entender melhor suas utilidades e quando aplicadas, pois não vejo muito como escolher entre eles. Pesquisei bastante, mas achei muita coisa tecnica que não me ajudou muito.

Comment: João, RMI, Socket e JPA são coisas completamente diferentes. É um pouco estranho que você esteja querendo "escolher" entre essas tecnologias. Você está querendo apenas aprender ou tem algum problema real que está enfrentando? Como você chegou à conclusão de que deve escolher uma dentre dessas tecnologias? Talvez seja melhor alterar sua pergunta e descrever melhor o problema, pois de outra forma seria muito amplo abordar todos os aspectos possíveis de cada uma dessas tecnologias.

Comment: **Sockets** basicamente transmitem dados em baixo nível entre programas remotos. **RMI** (*Remote Method Invocation*) é um pouco mais alto nível e permite que você execute um método de um programa remoto, aguardando o retorno como se fosse uma chamada de método local. **JPA** (*Java Persistence API*) é basicamente uma API de mapeamento objeto-relacional para acessar banco de dados sem escrever SQL. Bem, fiz um resumo de tudo, mas duvido que uma pesquisa não lhe desse essas definições. Portanto, é essencial que você seja mais claro em dizer qual é exatamente o seu problema. Abraço!

Comment: Essa parte ate tinha feito a pesquisa, e sim é por questão de aprendizagem, estou querendo ver se consigo criar um sisteminha cliente/servidor na web onde o servidor(web) enviaria os comandos a um programa (cliente) que executaria, no começo vi que a alternativa seria o **RMI** mas não achei tanto conteúdo do tema para iniciantes.

Comment: RMI não serve para cliente/servidor na web. Recomendo estudar alguma API RESTful como JAX-RS ou [Spring MVC](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/). Se quiser enviar mesmo uma notificação do servidor para o cliente (nem sempre isso é realmente necessário), estude sobre como usar WebSockets. [É possível fazer isso com o Spring também](http://syntx.io/using-websockets-in-java-using-spring-4/).

Comment: @utluiz
Obrigado pela luz, estudarei sim!

Answer (score 1):

Como foi comentado, essas três tecnologias tem finalidades MUITO diferentes. Não faz sentido compará-las.

- Remote Method Invocation (RMI) é um protocolo usado pelo Java para comunicação entre processos (programas) diferentes.
- Java Persistance API (JPA) é uma mini-linguagem que frameworks de persistência (Ex. Hibernate) usam para trabalhar com banco de dados.
- Socket é um ponto de comunicação entre processos através de uma rede de computadores. É conceito de baixo nível, inclusive o RMI usa sockets.

Pense no que você quer desenvolver e estude as tecnologias relevantes com calma! Não tente aprender tudo de uma vez. Qualquer dúvida, estamos aqui :)

Answer (score 1):

- RMI (Remote Method Invocation) é uma API que serve para você fazer chamadas de métodos remotas. Por exemplo, você consegue executar um método em outro computador.
- Socket seria um ponto de conexão entre dois computadores. Seria o IP e Porta de um computador.
- JPA é uma especificação. É uma especificação que permite que você consiga fazer o mapeamento objeto-relacional. O que seria? É você conseguir converter um código orientado a objetos em um código de um banco de dados.

Minhas definições foram um tanto quanto simplistas, espero que tenha entendido.